# How make a callback with PHP/JQuery/JSONP dynamic (Laravel project)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, callback, laravel-4

Right now I am working on a widget that I want certain people to put on their sites that will send info to them and get some info back.  Right now, I am having them use the following in their code:

```
<script src="http://myurl.com/widget/widgetscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="example-widget-container"></div>
```

Within widgetscript.js, I have the following bit:

```
var jsonp_url = "http://myurl.com/widget/external_widget?callback=?";
$.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
    $('#example-widget-container').html("This data comes from another server: " + data.msg);
});
```

The route that is called here calls a function in my WidgetController.php:

```
public function external_widget($id) {

    $array = Fan::likes_by_city($id);

    $data = "{msg:'Hello World!'}";

    if(array_key_exists('callback', $_GET)){

        header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example.com/');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 3628800');
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

        $callback = $_GET['callback'];
        echo $callback.'('.$data.');';

    } else {
        // normal JSON string
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf8');
        echo $data;
    }
```

I would like this function be dynamic so I can tailor the data in this function for every user that uses the widget (taking the $id as a parameter).  I know I can do this with my route like so:

```
Route::get('/widget/external_widget/{id?}', array('uses' => 'WidgetController@external_widget'));
```

Just adding the id parameter to the url.

However, in the code that is placed on the users side (the script and div), I see no way to make this dynamic.  Is there a way to get id data from a script or div that would change the widgetscript.js and thus the route called?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: You are trying to make someone else's website 'dynamic'? Unless you have control over their webpage, then how do you expect to be able to control the information on their site?

Comment: No No, make the widget dynamic.  Sorry this wasn't clear.  I want the widget to look different depending on the div they use (or some other input).

Comment: i dont understand your needs, when you say: "I would like this function be dynamic" you are referring to the php function public function external_widget($id) in your controller?

Answer (score 5):

You do that like any request: you add parameters to the url to customize the request.

A simple example would be to alter the `widgetscript.js` script to something like the following:

```
//create a function for your widget. 
//In javascript a function is also a class and this keeps all your variables and settings within your own scope so you dont have to worry about other scripts

//Keep in mind that I do some basic error checking, but not much.
//If you dont check for errors and a user provides wrong information he might get JS errors on his site.
//If you want to have a user friendly widget, make sure you check as much as possible and provide usefull information about the problems.

function MyCoolWidgetClass() {
  //In javascript it is possible to alter the reference to this, EG: using apply
  //To make sure you can always reference your own class, store the reference.
  var self = this;

  //define the basic settings
  self.defaultSettings = {
    container: '#example-widget-container',
    title: "Widget result",
    background: "#ccc",
    userId: 0
  }

  self.settings = {};

  //start your widget
  self.start = function(options) {  
    //merge the provided settings with the default settings
    $.extend(self.settings, self.defaultSettings, options);

    //check if the userid is provided
    //you could add more checks to validate the userId
    if (self.settings.userId==0) {
      alert("We need to know who you are");
      return;
    }

    var jsonp_url = "http://myurl.com/widget/external_widget?userId="+self.settings.userId+"&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(jsonp_url, function(data) {
        //create the response
        //This is just to show how you could use the settings to show a title or anyting else.
        //Again, you could check if the settings are correct.
        var html = '<div class="title">'+self.settings.title+'</div><div class="content" style="background:'+self.settings.background+'">'+data.msg+'</div>';

        //add it to the provided container
        //keep in mind that a user could provide a container like '.items' or 'div' and then it will be added to multiple instances
        $(self.settings.container).html(html);
    });
  }
}
//create a globally approachable instance of your class
window.MyCoolWidget = new MyCoolWidgetClass();
```

Now the user can add your widget to his site and provide some options.

```
<script src="http://myurl.com/widget/widgetscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
  //notice that I dont provide a background, and thus the default will be used.
  MyCoolWidget.start({title: "Another title", container: "#mywidgetcontainer", userId: 10});
});
</script>
<div id="mywidgetcontainer"></div>
```

Now i'm not sure what your responds will be, but in most cases it's not advisable to simple use the actual userid. One could simple use another number to check the response for somebody else.

Since everybody can just look at the JS code when visiting your website (the website where the widget is) you can never realy prevent people from using somebody else his ID, but if the ID is a long random case sensitive key, atleast they cannot guess other accounts to abuse your service. For instance if you have a limit of 1000 request per ID per day or something.

[JSFiddle that shows your IP adres using this widget](http://jsfiddle.net/wKtNe/1/)